# Merge by year-week, plus or minus n weeks in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
aa = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','b'],
             'week': ['2022-W13','2022-W14', '2022-W19', '2022-W14']})
bb = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
              'week': ['2022-W12','2022-W13','2022-W14','2022-W15','2022-W16','2022-W20',
                      '2022-W13','2022-W14','2022-W15','2022-W16'],
             'val': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

id      week
0  a  2022-W13
1  a  2022-W14
2  a  2022-W19
3  b  2022-W14
  id      week  val
0  a  2022-W12    0
1  a  2022-W13    1
2  a  2022-W14    2
3  a  2022-W15    3
4  a  2022-W16    4
5  a  2022-W20    5
6  b  2022-W13    6
7  b  2022-W14    7
8  b  2022-W15    8
9  b  2022-W16    9
```

I would like to merge the two dataframes by `id` and `week`, but the `week` I want to give a **plus or minus 1 week**.

Explanation:

- for the first row of `aa` where `id=='a'` and `week='2022-W13'`, i would have to get the rows from `bb` where `id=='a'` and `week='2022-W12'` or `week='2022-W13'` or `week='2022-W14'`
- for the second row of `aa` where `id=='a'` and `week='2022-W14'`, i would have to get the rows from `bb` where `id=='a'` and `week='2022-W13'` or `week='2022-W14'` or `week='2022-W15'`
- etc

The output datafame should be this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b'],
              'week': ['2022-W12','2022-W13','2022-W14','2022-W15','2022-W20',
                      '2022-W13','2022-W14','2022-W15'],
             'val': [0,1,2,3,5,
                     6,7,8]})

id  week    val
0   a   2022-W12    0
1   a   2022-W13    1
2   a   2022-W14    2
3   a   2022-W15    3
4   a   2022-W20    5
5   b   2022-W13    6
6   b   2022-W14    7
7   b   2022-W15    8
```

Comment: Is all your data for one single year? If not, what should happen for 2022-W52 or 2023-W1?

Comment: @not_speshal it can be different years as well. If the week is `2022-W52`, then the next week is `2023-W1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could repeat the dataframe with +/- 1 week and then merge:

```
#get the date (Monday of the week) from the week column
aa["week"] = pd.to_datetime(aa["week"]+"-1", format="%Y-W%W-%w")

#repeat the dataframe with +/- 1 week
left = pd.concat([aa, aa.assign(week=aa["week"]+pd.DateOffset(days=-7)),aa.assign(week=aa["week"]+pd.DateOffset(days=7))])

#convert date back to week number to merge
left["week"] = left["week"].dt.strftime("%Y-W%W")

#merge to get the output
output = left.drop_duplicates().sort_values(by=["id","week"]).merge(bb)

>>> output
  id      week  val
0  a  2022-W12    0
1  a  2022-W13    1
2  a  2022-W14    2
3  a  2022-W15    3
4  a  2022-W20    5
5  b  2022-W13    6
6  b  2022-W14    7
7  b  2022-W15    8
```

Comment: what if the plus or minus week is 2 ? Then if I change the `pd.DateOffset(days=-7)` to `pd.DateOffset(days=-14)` I am missing some weeks at the `left` dataframe

Comment: Yes, just change 7 to 14 if you want to offset by 2 weeks.

Comment: but then `left` looks like this 

```id week
0 a 2022-W11
1 a 2022-W12
0 a 2022-W13
1 a 2022-W14
0 a 2022-W15
1 a 2022-W16
2 a 2022-W17
2 a 2022-W19
2 a 2022-W21
3 b 2022-W12
3 b 2022-W14
3 b 2022-W16```
 As you can see it misses week 18 and week 20 for `id=='a'`

Comment: You want to include 1 week and 2 weeks then. Using 14 ONLY gives 2 week offsets. Using 7 ONLY gives 1 week offsets. You need to `concat` using 7 and 14. So 4 different tables in the `concat`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def convert_to_datetime(row):
    year, week_number = row['week'].split('-W')
    base_date = pd.to_datetime(f"{year}-W{int(week_number)-1}-1", format="%Y-W%U-%w")
    one_week_later = base_date + pd.DateOffset(weeks=1)
    one_week_earlier = base_date + pd.DateOffset(weeks=2)
    return base_date, one_week_later, one_week_earlier

# Apply the conversion function to the 'week' column and expand the result into new columns
aa['week'] = aa.apply(convert_to_datetime, axis=1)
aa = aa.explode(column='week').reset_index(drop=True)

def convert_to_week_format(row):
    return f"{row.year}-W{row.weekofyear}"

# # Convert the new datetime columns back to the original week format
aa['week'] = aa['week'].apply(convert_to_week_format)


aa.merge(bb).drop_duplicates()
```

---

**Output:**

```
    id  week       val
0   a   2022-W12    0
1   a   2022-W13    1
3   a   2022-W14    2
5   a   2022-W15    3
6   a   2022-W20    5
7   b   2022-W13    6
8   b   2022-W14    7
9   b   2022-W15    8
```